# Remove VLAN tag from incoming traffic (Ubiquiti Edgerouter)

Tags: vlan, ubiquiti

On eth4 I have incoming traffic from the WiFi AP. Some is tagged with VID 102 and some with VID 950. I want the Ubiquiti Edgerouter (which is currently acting as a managed switch) to take the 950 VLAN traffic and simply remove the tag, passing it off as now untagged traffic.

Does this question even make sense? If it does, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Wi-Fi doesn't actually tag the frames the way ethernet does. Ethernet and Wi-Fi frames are different. The WAP will separate the VLANs into different SSIDs. There was a propsed standard to let two point-to-point WAPs use VLAN tags, but that is poorly supported, and I'm not sure the standard was ever ratified.

Comment: @RonMaupin But on the switch connect to the AP, I do indeed see packets incoming tagged with VID 950.

Comment: Yes, to and from the switch. The switch VLAN translates to the WAP SSID, and what a WAP receives on a particular SSID gets converted to a VLAN on a trunk to the switch. If you do not want to trunk with the switch, then the switch interface needs to be an access interface, although that is a security risk because then the WAP management is also on the same network as the users. If you only want one SSID, then create a trunk to the WAP, and the WAP management will be on the native (untagged) VLAN, and the network for the users will be on the tagged VLAN.

Comment: In any case, the frames sent to the users do not have VLAN tags as that is not part of Wi-Fi.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin The question ended up becoming irrelevant as I took a different approach to solve the problem at hand. I will remove the question. EDIT: But the answer is appropriate so I will just leave it and mark it as correct.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm just doing a little year-end cleanup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WAP tags frames on its Ethernet port depending on their source/destination SSID (SSID/VLAN association). That is required to keep SSIDs and VLANs separate.

Simply configure the switch port that is passing on the traffic as untagged port for VID 950. VLAN 950 frames will continue to be tagged between WAP and switch. When passing on those frames the switch removes the tag, according to the egress port's configuration.